# Pin nodejs version on Alpine without building from source

Tags: node.js, docker, kibana, alpine-linux

I am trying to install Kibana 6.7.0 on Docker. Base inherited `FROM behance/docker-nginx:8.5-alpine`
Kibana throws an error stating it requires node version `10.15.2`
because alpine default offers `10.16.0` from the apk repo.

I tried pinning down node version like this

```
curl -O https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.15.2/node-v10.15.2-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar xzf node-v10.15.2-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

and 
`ENV PATH="/node-v10.15.2-linux-x64/bin:${PATH}"`

When I do `node -v` 
I get an error saying node `/node-v10.15.2-linux-x64/bin/node` not found even though it is present.

Is it possible to install node `10.15.2` without building from the source?

Comment: If it is node you care about, why not use the node:*-alpine images? (Where * is the specific Node version you want)

Comment: I *have* to use the base nginx image because there are certain constraints from security at the org level.

Comment: Security constraints w.r.t. base image? If so, doesn’t downloading binaries into that image sort of invalidate the whole idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have no chance.

In fact although the latest alpine use `node10.16`, see [this](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=v3.10), but your alpine version is v3.9, which use `node10.14`, see [this](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=v3.9). I don't know if you can use `node10.14` to make you work, but you do not have chance to use `apk add` to install `node10.15` version as they even not stored in apk central repo.

And, download prebuilt package like `https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.15.2/node-v10.15.2-linux-x64.tar.gz` from official site definitely not work for you. This is because alpine use `musl libc` while official nodejs binary was built with `glibc` which is more common libc in linux world. A similar discussion for you reference is [here](https://github.com/nodejs/nodejs.org/issues/1569).

As a result, the only solution is to use source to build, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/f8f2384f7edc345f5ffc0496458005981b512882/10/alpine/Dockerfile) to add your things to your dockerfile. Additional, [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) is preferred in your scenario.

Comment: Or just use multistage to copy the node files over from the official node-alpine image. If build times are a concern, that should speed things up a bit.

Comment: @Krumelur Yes, that could be a solution, just I don't know if nodejs related files will be scattered in different corners of node-alpine rootfs which make copy not so easy. Anyway, this could be a good thought.

Comment: @atline were you able to find solution to this? Appreciate if you can share it.